# Calling Web API with Singular or Plural Controller URIs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Most examples of Web API that I've seen show URIs in this format:

```
/api/values/   (returns all records)
/api/value/{id}    (returns a specific record)
```

I can think of times I would not like this URI convention, but for my current project it's perfect. Though, it's not working for me and I don't know what I could have done to effect this. For me, I can have one or the other - singular or plural.

If my controller class is named ValuesController, then my Web API is

```
/api/values/
/api/values/{id}
```

If my controller class is named ValueController, then my Web API is

```
/api/value/
/api/value/{id}
```

I used ADO.NET Entity Data Model to create several entities in model designer. All have a singular naming convention. For example, Activity, State, Country, User, etc. Though, EF appears to create plural database tables no matter.

I created APIControllers for each of these entities. I've tried 2 naming conventions with my controllers - both plural and singular, but I am not seeing the expected (and desired) results with the URIs. The plural and singular Web API are always the same no matter what I try.

FYI, I just checked the default API that is created automatically (ValuesController). To return all records I have to specify /api/values/ and to return a single record I have to specify /api/values/{id} - both are plural and I'm sure it wasn't that way by default.

What effects this? Where is the logic that configures/recognizes a distinguished form of the URI for plural and singular?

Comment: "I'm sure it wasn't that way by default." - it was.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default route that is configured in Web API's `RouteConfig.cs` file specifies a parameter named `controller`, similar to this:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute("Default", "api/{controller}/{id}",
    new { id = RouteParameter.Optional };
```

When you're making a call to either `/api/values` or `/api/values/{id}`, the route value for your controller will be `values` in both cases. Consequently, the controller that Web API resolves by convention will be the `ValuesController`.

*(Note that there's **no** automatic pluralization performed **whatsoever**. You can implement a custom `IHttpControllerSelector`, if you really wanted to implement that behavior. I strongly recommend not to do that, though.)*

Comment: Somehow I misunderstood this then. It "seems" like every tutorial I've ever read/watched on creating ASP Web API showed a singular and plural URI for the resource. Thank you for straightening me out on that.

Comment: @rwkiii The idea behind pluralized entity names are *resources*, to mention some RESTful slang. The `{id}` parameter narrows down the resource (a collection) you're querying to a single item with a specific ID. You could also configure additional routes, such as `api/values/recent` or `api/values/popular`. I think you get the idea.

Comment: If you prefer to have both "value" and "values" URIs, you can create two controllers, or else use attribute routing (which is still in RC).

Comment: @rkwii , so what did you end doing to resolve this? I have the same issue..how do the tutorials get the plural and singular routes in one controller then?

Comment: @Neville: If you really want both singular and plural routes to actions in the same controller, apply route attributes to the action methods in Web API 2, eg `[Route("api/v2/order/{id}")]`, `[Route("api/v2/orders/search")]`.  However, I've read an article that suggests always using plural, to represent a collection of resources, and treating any ID as an index into the collection which will return a single resource.  eg api/v2/orders/ represents a collection of orders, while the 123456 in api/v2/order/123456 is an index into that collection, pointing to a single resource. I like that idea.

Comment: @Simon Tewsi : Unless you meant to type  api/v2/orders/123456 (plural), your last sentence contradicts itself. Either way, these type of coding suggestions border on cover-ups for lack of functionality or proper explanation. The original question of how these tutorial gurus get both singular and plural routes in one API, never got answered.

Comment: @Neville: Oops, well caught.  That was indeed a typo and should have been api/v2/orders/123456.  I notice the question was from October 2013, around the time Web API 2.0 was released, so I'm not sure if it was relating to Web API 1.0 or 2.0. I've no idea how you could mix singular and plural in Web API 1.0.  However, in Web API 2.0 applying RouteAttributes to the different action methods in the controller will allow mixing of singular and plural in the same controller.